# why SomeClass::class is KClass<SomeClass> but this::class is KClass<out SomeClass>

Tags: reflection, kotlin

I want to print values of properties of my class.

```
fun print() {
    val cl = this::class
    cl.declaredMemberProperties.filter {it.visibility != KVisibility.PRIVATE}.forEach {
        println("${it.name} = ${it.get(this)}")
    }
}
```

When I try to build this code I get compiler error:

```
Error:(34, 40) Kotlin: Out-projected type 'KProperty1<out SomeClass, Any?>' prohibits the use of 'public abstract fun get(receiver: T): R defined in kotlin.reflect.KProperty1'
```

When I change `this` to class name `SomeClass` everything is fine

```
fun print() {
    val cl = SomeClass::class
    cl.declaredMemberProperties.filter {it.visibility != KVisibility.PRIVATE}.forEach {
        println("${it.name} = ${it.get(this)}")
    }
}
```

So the problem is that compiler changers type of `this::class` to `KClass<out SomeClass>` instead of using `KClass<SomeClass>`. Any idea why does it happen?

Answer (score 9):

The reason for this difference is that, when you use the `SomeClass::class` reference, it is sure to be the class token representing `SomeClass` and not one of its possible derived classes, therefore it is `KClass<SomeClass>` without type projections.

But `this::class` written in a function of an `open` or `abstract` class or an extension function can return a class token of a derived class, therefore, to ensure type safety, the [type is `out`-projected](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#type-projections): `KClass<out SomeClass>` means that the actual type argument can be `SomeClass` or its subtype.

Example:

```
open class A {
    fun f() {
        println(this::class) // KClass<out A> because it can be KClass<B>
    }
}

class B : A()

B().f()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. it is very helpful.